# property not working as intended

Tags: python

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property, and have written the following script:

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self.temperature = temperature

    def get_temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self._temperature

    def set_temperature(self, value):
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
        print("Setting value")
        self._temperature = value

    temperature = property(get_temperature, set_temperature)


c = Celsius()

print c.temperature
c.temperature = 100
print c.temperature
```

When I run the script, I simply see the two temperature values:

```
0
100
```

However, I would expect the `Getting value` and `Setting value` print statements to be visible as well. Is the `property` somehow not working properly?

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: by setting c.temperature, you don't actually call the method set_temperature but the method `c.__setattr__` with the following arguments c.__setattr__("temperature", 100). So what you want to override is the `__setattr__` method

Comment: If it's Python 2, the problem is that your class doesn't inherit from `object`, so it is an old-style class. Change the first line to `class Celsius(object):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do only works in new-style classes. To declare a new-style class in Python 2, you need to have

```
class Celsius(object):
```

instead of

```
class Celsius:
```

In Python 3, all classes are new-style, so the plain `class Celsius` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The code should work as is, but you're mixing Python 2 syntax with Python 3.

---

If you turn the `print` statements outside the class into *function calls*, the code works fine as valid Python 3.

If you'll run this as Python 2 code, then you have to inherit your class from `object` and keep every other thing as is.

---

Choose one.

Answer (score 1):

you need define class as this:

```
class Celsius(object):
    balabala
    balabala
```